# Why does this switch statement not work?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, hashcode

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VerticalWire {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("how many wires");
        String howManyWires = in.next();

        switch(howManyWires) {
            case "3":
            {
                 System.out.println("true");
                 break;
            }

            case "3 5":
            {
                 System.out.println("false");break;}
            }
     }
}
```

I tested if I enter "3 5" it returns true even though I think it should return false!
What is wrong?

Comment: What do you think `in.next()` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: `in.next()` only reads the first number. use `nextLine()`

Comment: Have a read of what [`Scanner#next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) actually does, then use `Scanner#nextLine` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use [`in.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) instead of `in.next()`.

Documentation of [`scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) states that

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

So when you enter `3 5` as input, it will read only 3 when you call next method and if you again call next method then it will read 5.

Comment: Why should they? (I know the answer, but you need to tell the OP ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer - You don't have to say - *I know the answer*. We know you know :P

Comment: @TheLostMind People often mistaken me for the OP ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - If only they knew how to hover the mouse over a person's name :)